# PostgreSQL: Join 2 arrays with maximum values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an table with 2 records ( illustrative purpose )

```
| id      | access (int array) |
| ---------------------------- |
| 1       | {0,1,0}            | 
| 2       | {1,0,0}            |
```

I'd like to select both values and merge them together
to get the highest value making the result in this case:

```
{1,1,0}
```

The access array could grow to over 200 values and therefor i'd like to avoid to do it in the programming code, ( golang ).

Basically it is the same as this question : [Merge two (or more) arrays and keep values that are highest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231105/merge-two-or-more-arrays-and-keep-values-that-are-highest) but in my case the seperated columns are combined into one field with an array.

**UPDATES**

1. The `row(access)` array's always have the same amount of values

Comment: Yes, `each rows(access)` have the same number of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query ([SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b02932/1)):

```
select array_agg(elem)
from (
    select distinct on (row_number) row_number, elem 
    from (
        select id, elem, row_number() over (partition by id)
        from (
            select id, unnest(access) elem
            from merge_test
            where id in (1,2)
            ) sub
        ) sub
    order by 1, 2 desc
    ) sub;
```

---

**Binary arrays**

If the arrays contain only '0' and '1' and have the same number of values:

```
create table merge_binary_test (id int, access int[]);
insert into merge_binary_test values
(1, '{0,1,0,1}'),
(2, '{1,0,0,1}');

select string_to_array(bit_or(elem)::text, null)::int[]
from (
    select id, array_to_string(access, '')::varbit elem
    from merge_binary_test
    where id in (1,2)
    ) sub

 string_to_array
-----------------
 {1,1,0,1}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider following as an example:

```
create table arr(id int,access int[]);
insert into arr values (1,'{0,1,0}'),(2,'{0,1,0}'),(3,'{0,0,9}');
```

so that the rows will be:

```
id access  
-- ------- 
1  {0,1,0} 
2  {0,1,0} 
3  {0,0,9}
```

Now a function can be created to merge array rows like below:

```
CREATE
    OR replace FUNCTION merge_array (
    arrval INT -- the total number of values in an array in my example its 3, but 200 is for yours
    ,tbl TEXT --name of the table in which you want perform this function,
    ,col TEXT -- name of the array col
    )
RETURNS setof INTEGER [] AS $$

DECLARE qry TEXT;

BEGIN
    SELECT format('select translate(string_to_array(x.*::text,'','')::text,''()'','''')::int[] from (select %s  from (select ' || col || ' ar  from  ' || tbl || ' ) as sq) as x ', egn)
    INTO qry
    FROM (
        SELECT string_agg('max(ar[' || val || '])', ',') egn
        FROM (
            SELECT generate_series(1, arrval) val
            ) t
        ) tt;

    RETURN QUERY

    EXECUTE (qry);
END;$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Usage : `select merge_array(3,'arr','access')`
Result:

```
merge_array 
----------- 
{0,1,9}
```